# How to collapse product categories for WooCommmerce

Tags: woocommerce

All product categories and subcategories are expanded automatically. The categories and subcategories can not be collapsed.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I44zv.jpg)
I want to expand product categories chosen and collapse other categories in views. For example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5qJj.jpg)
Maybe it must override the TS-Product Categories widget and write the custom codes ( CSS & JS ). Now I want to go to wp-content/plugins/themesky/widgets/product_categories.php and override it as requested. Please help me to offer the custom codes?
Thanks in advance!!

Please offer me the custom codes.